# Delphi - Tree View

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, delphi-2006

I am looking for a data aware Tree View for delphi

what is the best one to use ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would recommend the [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExQuantumTreeList/) QuantumTreeList. It looks really nice, is fast and data aware.

Answer (score 18):

Virtual TreeView is the fastest, with most features, the best and its free!
(for data aware there are free descants of it, also on that following page)

you will find it here:
[virtual treeview control on softgems](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php/controls/virtual-treeview)

here is a tutorial video (in german):
[DelphiPraxis Stammtisch Videos](http://www.delphipraxis.net/videos#Stammtisch_2)

there was also a tutor in the german magazin "entwickler magazin"
Editions: 02/08, 03/08 and 04/08.
[Entwickler Magazin](http://entwickler-magazin.de/)

Answer (score 5):

Virtual TreeView

Answer (score 5):

Here is the (not easy to find) VirtualTreeView SVN repository url:

<del>svn://www.soft-gems.net/library/VirtualTreeview</del>

**UPDATE:** Mike moved the sources to Google Code:

http://virtual-treeview.googlecode.com/svn/trunk